# Tridion core service How to download binary file of a multimedia component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, core-services

I have a requirement where I need to download binary file of a multimedia component but when I access the properties exposed of `BinaryContentData` class then there is no property to download an image file. Although for uploading file, Core Service have a property namely `UploadFromFile`.

So is there a way to download binary file to a temp location. Below is the code I am using:

```
core_service.ServiceReference1.SessionAwareCoreService2010Client client = new SessionAwareCoreService2010Client(); 
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUserName"; 
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword"; client.Open();
ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.TryCheckOut(
                            multimediaComponentURI, new ReadOptions());
BinaryContentData binaryData =   component.BinaryContent;
```

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a helper function called `streamDownloadClient.DownloadBinaryContent` inside **Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll** that you can use.

I have created the following function that I usually reuse for that purpose:

```csharp
private static void CreateBinaryFromMultimediaComponent(string tcm)
{
    Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.StreamDownloadClient streamDownloadClient = new StreamDownloadClient();
    SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("netTcp_2011");

    ComponentData multimediaComponent = client.Read(tcm, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;

    // Generate you own file name, and file location
    string file = "D:\\MyTempLocation\\" + Path.GetFilename(multimediaComponent.BinaryContent.Filename);;     

    // Write out the existing file from Tridion
    FileStream fs = File.Create(file);
    byte[] binaryContent = null;

    if (multimediaComponent.BinaryContent.FileSize != -1)
    {
        Stream tempStream = streamDownloadClient.DownloadBinaryContent(tcm);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        tempStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        binaryContent = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    fs.Write(binaryContent, 0, binaryContent.Length);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: For using above code, you may also need to increase size of following attributes in 'streamDownload_basicHttp_2010 'endpoint:-                                    maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824". By default they have value as "65536"

Comment: you might need to use this code to get proper filepath string file = "D:\\MyTempLocation\\" + Path.GetFileName(multimediaComponent.BinaryContent.Filename);